# Write plain moddatetime procedute to use in triggers

Tags: postgresql, psql

My cloud provider won't allow me to install the `moddatetime` extension. However, my DB schema relies on the `moddatetime` procedure.

How could I write a plain PSQL drop-in replacement for the `moddatetime(colname)` function that can be used in place of this extension ? ([Here is the specification of this extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-spi.html#id-1.11.7.50.8))

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION moddatetime() RETURNS trigger
  -- ???
```

Comment: What should it do?

Comment: Be used as a drop-in replacement of the `moddatetime` function provided by the `moddatetime` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will act as a drop-in replacement for `moddatetime`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moddatetime() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $moddatetime$
  DECLARE
    colname name;
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_NARGS = 1) THEN
      colname = TG_ARGV[0];
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'moddatetime(colname) requires one argument';
    END IF;

    RETURN json_populate_record(NEW, json_build_object(colname, NOW()));
  END;
$moddatetime$;
```

If you want to use the native one and fallback if the native extension cannot be installed, use the following:

```sql
DO $SETUP_MODDATETIME$
BEGIN
  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "moddatetime";
EXCEPTION WHEN INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGE THEN
  -- Unable to use moddatetime extension, so create a function instead
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moddatetime() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $moddatetime$
    DECLARE
      colname name;
    BEGIN
      IF (TG_NARGS = 1) THEN
        colname = TG_ARGV[0];
      ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'moddatetime(colname) requires one argument';
      END IF;

      RETURN json_populate_record(NEW, json_build_object(colname, NOW()));
    END;
  $moddatetime$;
END $SETUP_MODDATETIME$;
```